# Get camera matrix from object transformation matrix

Tags: graphics, geometry, computer-vision

I have a transformation matrix of 3d object in world space with a fixed camera position. I would like to derive the camera matrix (position, look up vector, right vector) if the object wasn't transformed and the camera was transformed instead. How could I compute that? Hope my question makes sense

Comment: Rotating and then translating the object is done by `M1= T*R`. Transforming the camera instead is done with `M2`. The point is that if the object is seen from the camera *same for both options* that means `M1=M2`

Comment: This [lookAt link](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) shows how to derive the matrix when the camera is transformed.

Comment: see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) so for example you just translate behind the object |(relative to it) and do an inverse to obtain the camera matrix with follow mode ... but of coarse you have to take your conventions ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Premise. Let's represent coordinate transformations with 4x4 matrices. Specifically, the 4x4 matrix **`Qab`** representing the coordinate transform of frame `a` from frame `b` is such that:

- Its 3x3 upper-left submatrix is the rotation matrix **`Rab`**, i.e. the 3x3 orthonormal matrix whose columns are the ordinately the components of the **`x_b`**, **`y_b`**, **`z_b`** unit vectors of frame `b`, decomposed in frame `a`.
- Its 3x1 upper-right submatrix is the translation vector **`t_ab`** from the origin of frame `a` to the origin of frame `b`, decomposed in frame `a`.
- Its 4th row is [0, 0, 0, 1].
- If **`p`** is a point whose coordinates in frame `b` are **`p_b`**`= [px_b, py_b, pz_b, 1]`, then the coordinates **`p_a`**`= [px_a, py_a, pz_a, 1]` of the same point in frame in frame `a` are given by **`p_a.T`**`=`**`Qab * p_b.T`**, where `x.T` means the transposed of vector `x`. Note that we append a `1` as a dummy fourth coordinate in order to be able to multiply 3D points by 4x4 matrices.

Now, to your question. Let **`Qcw`** be the 4x4 matrix representing the rotation and translation of the camera from the world reference frame, and **`Qow`** the  analogous transformation of the object from the world.

Then your answer is the camera-from-object transform **`Qco`**. We can compute it by noting that we can go from frame `o` to frame `c` by first going from `o` to `w`, and then from `w` to `c`. Therefore it is **`Qco`**`=`**`Qcw * Qwo`**, where **`Qwo`**`=`**`inv(Qow)`** is the inverse of **`Qow`**, and represents the world frame as seen from the object.

Comment: A little bit complicated but I got it. Thanks